# Override property conflict

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two complex class:

```
public class BaseRepository<EntityType> where EntityType : class
{
    protected northwindDataContext context = new northwindDataContext();

    public EntityType Get(object id)
    {
        return context.Set<EntityType>().Find(id);
    }

    public EntityType Save(EntityType entity)
    {
        // Do generic save things
    }
}

public class BaseService<EntityType> where EntityType : class
{
    public BaseRepository<EntityType> repo = new BaseRepository<EntityType>();

    public EntityType Get(object id)
    {
        // Do generic get entities
        return repo.Get(id);
    }
}
```

Then i have multiple "services" class where sometimes (Not always) i need to "replace" the repository to add some "extra" funcionality.

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>
{
    public User Get(object id)
    {
        // Do specific user get including Role DP
        return context.Users.Include("Role").Find(id);
    }
}

public class UserService : BaseService<User>
{
    public UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
}
```

Using this format the instance of UserService call to BaseRepository.Get() instead of UserRepository.Get().

The only way to do what i want is replicate code like this:

```
public class UserService : BaseService<User>
{
    public UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();

    public User Get(object id)
    {
        // This call to UserRepository.Get()
        return repo.Get(id);
    }
}
```

The real problem is that i have 29 "Repositories", so i need add "Get(int)", "Get(predicate)", "Save(entity)", "Save(IEnumerable)", "Delete(entity)" and "Delete(IEnumerable)", and that makes a kind of awkward code.

Is there any way to replace the property "repo" in BaseService so that BaseService methods call the repo subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is for the `BaseService<T>.repo` field (it's a field, not a property - and I'd discourage you from using public fields, but that's a different matter) to be the appropriate kind of repository for the type. That's easy enough to do - just don't create it in `BaseService<T>`. Instead, pass it up the constructor chain:

```
// Type parameter renamed to follow normal .NET naming conventions
public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly BaseRepository<T> repo;

    protected BaseService(BaseRepository<T> repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public T Get(object id)
    {
        // Do generic get entities
        return repo.Get(id);
    }
}

public class UserService : BaseService<User>
{
    public UserService() : base(new UserRepository())
    {
    }
}
```

In fact, if `UserService` isn't providing any other value, you may only need a `Service<T>`, non-abstract and with a *public* constructor to take the repo. Then you'd just use:

```
var userService = new Service<User>(new UserRepository());
```

for example.

Comment: The best part of this is that is is now DI friendly.

Comment: I really do that, but i cant override the Get method on UseRepository if BaseRepository have defined "Get". BaseRepository.Get() should return         context.Set<EntityType>().Find(id) only If the overrided repo has not this method.

Comment: Thanks for everything. I resolve this with your help and adding "virtual" to BaseService.Get() and "override" to UserService.Get()

Comment: @Pythonizo: Why do that? In the code you showed in the question, in both cases you were just calling `repo.Get(id)` - so why would you need to override the behaviour in `UserService`?

Comment: I see my error and create a constructor in baseservice without parameters.
protected BaseService()
    {
        this.repo = new BaseRepository<T>();
    }